Как вывести список всех городов со своим временем? pytz
Выводится либо список всех город без времени, либо только один город со своим временем.
Нужный пример:
Europe/Moscow 2024-11-27 16:51:09.904632+03:00
Europe/London 2024-11-27 13:51:09.905633+00:00
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

all_city = pytz.all_timezones

data2 = []
for i in (all_city):
    print(i)

Moscow_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
now = datetime.now(Moscow_tz)
print(now)

London_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
now2 = datetime.now(London_tz)
print(now2)


Почему просто так не сработает?
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

all_city = pytz.all_timezones

my_city = ["Europe/Moscow", "Europe/London"]

for city in my_city:
    timezone = pytz.timezone(city)
    now = datetime.now(timezone)
    print(f"{city} {now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')}")

Если вам нужны все города - передайте вместо my_city - all_city

Спасибо за ответ.

Я только учусь и не могу понять. Почему методы библиотеки datetime  можно применить к pytz? ну есть в pytz список городов, откуда datetime знает, сколько времени в каждом городе?

@Gold_boomber документация в помощь! Если говорить простым языком - pytz это просто база данных со всем временными зонами, оформленная специально для библиотеки datetime
https://pypi.org/project/pytz/
https://pypi.org/project/DateTime/

Спасибо за ответ.
